# Trying to print out different message depending on the value of an instance

Tags: java, class, object, instance

heres my code:

```
public class auditorForum {
   int pastMonthSpend;

  public auditorForum(int spending){
      spending = pastMonthSpend;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      auditorForum October = new auditorForum(1433);
      if (October >= 1000) {
        if (October <= 1500){
          System.out.println("Eligible");
        } else {
          System.out.println("Ineligible");
        }
      }
    }
}
```

It results in

```
auditorForum.java:9: error: bad operand types for binary operator '>='
      if (October >= 1000) {
                  ^
  first type:  auditorForum
  second type: int
1 error
```

and im not sure what the fix is, ive tried making separate values for the minimum and maximum values (1000 and 1500) but no

Comment: You can't use `>=` and `<=` on your own custom class directly. You could however use it on the int field your class has: `if(October.pastMonthSpend >= 1000)`

Comment: As an aside, by convention class names start with an upper case letter (so `AuditorForum`) while variable names start with a lower case letter (so `october`).

Comment: There a various problems in your code: The assignment in the constructor is wrong (has to be flipped to work). Your are trying to compare an object instance (October) to an int, where you probably would want to compare October's pastMonthSpend with that int. Also check Java code conventions, e.g. https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf. For a start...

Answer (score 1):

Two mistakes I see and have corrected. please find the below program.
October is reference variable for the newly created object. so you should use October.pastMonthSpend and another issue is in a constructor, you have to assign value this way pastMonthSpend=spending;

```
public class Demo123 {
    int pastMonthSpend;

    public Demo123(int spending){
        pastMonthSpend=spending;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("hii");
        Demo123 October = new Demo123(1433);
        if (October.pastMonthSpend >= 1000) {
            if (October.pastMonthSpend <= 1500){
                System.out.println("Eligible");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Ineligible");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post.

Answer (score 0):

"October" is an object instance. You have to access the integer variable "pastMonthSpend" for the comparison. and variable value assigning should be  pastMonthSpend = spending; not  spending = pastMonthSpend;